# How to use a Windows native dll in a Mozilla Firefox 32+ add-on?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I’d like to resurrect an abandoned add-on that was created for Firefox 11. This add-on controlled a device via a native dll. With the Firefox 32 addon-api and ctx, I don’t see how to:

1)  insert lengthy custom init code into bootstrap.js or harness-options.json.

2)  include additional binaries into the xpi archive

3)  discover or determine the executable path for use of external code within my add-on

I have a copy of the original old xpi. I can see how they put the required dll in “.\plugins\5.9.6.0000\foobar.dll”. I can see they used the “install” function in .\bootstrap.js. I’ve included some of the the original code from bootstrap.js here.

```
function registerPlugin()
{
   var profPath = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].getService( Components.interfaces.nsIProperties).get("ProfD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile).path;  
var wrk = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/windows-registry-key;1"]
                    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowsRegKey);
wrk.open(wrk.ROOT_KEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE", wrk.ACCESS_ALL);
if(!wrk.hasChild("MozillaPlugins"))
  wrk = wrk.createChild("MozillaPlugins", wrk.ACCESS_ALL);  
else
  wrk = wrk.openChild("MozillaPlugins", wrk.ACCESS_ALL);
var t1 = wrk.createChild("blueglow@hardcorps.com", wrk.ACCESS_ALL);
t1.writeStringValue("Description", "CanCan extension for BagMan");         
t1.writeStringValue("ProductName", "CanCan extension for BagMan");
t1.writeStringValue("Vendor", "Hardcorps Inc.");
t1.writeStringValue("Version", "5.9.6.0000");
t1.writeStringValue("Path", profPath + "\\extensions\\blueglow@hardcorps.com\\plugins\\5.9.6.0000\\foobar.dll" );
var t2 = t1.createChild("MimeTypes", wrk.ACCESS_ALL);
t2.createChild("application/blueglow-ff-plugin", wrk.ACCESS_ALL);
t2.close();
t1.close();
wrk.close();

Components.classes['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1']
                       .getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator)
                       .getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser')
                       .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                       .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
                       .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
                       .rootTreeItem
                       .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                       .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow).navigator.plugins.refresh(false);
}


function install(data, reason)
{
  registerPlugin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the dll into your addon and then use it via js-ctypes.

Here's an example on Mac, they use .dylib instead of .dll:

source: https://github.com/vasi/firefox-dock-progress/tree/master

compiled source: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/files/browse/185970/file/chrome/content/DockProgress.jsm

Comment: Thank you.
Unfortunately, this example is for Firefox 4-11 and seems even older then the Windows add-on example I have. And because it is OSX, I can't build it to test has well it holds up to FF 32. What MAY be useful info is that this example dumps everything into the "chrome/dockprogress/content" folder, and the javascript seems to assume a path of "." I don't know if that will work for me.

Comment: `var file = this.getFile("chrome://dockprogress/content/DockProgressC.dylib"); var lib = this.lib = ctypes.open(file);` its done the exact same way in windows. It was same as it was back in FF4-11

Comment: Btw if you are using addon-sdk drop your dll in the data folder and then do: `ctypes.open(self.data.url('my.dll'))`